# Resizing Image (create thumbnail) on ftp_put

Tags: php, image, ftp, put

So I have a simple goal but I can't seem to get the one part to work.

1) Upload an image and create 3 different sizes: LG, MD, SM; then rename images.

2) Move the images from server/website A to server/website B.

I have the uploading and renaming working for all three images, but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong with the re-sizing part. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Note: I am currently trying to just get one image to resize, I figured one at a time would be smartest to make sure I understand what is happening.

Code:

```
function thumb_resize_image_new($source, $destination, $image_type, $max_size, $image_width, $image_height, $quality){

    if($image_width <= 0 || $image_height <= 0){return false;} //return false if nothing to resize

    //do not resize if image is smaller than max size
    if($image_width <= $max_size && $image_height <= $max_size){
        return true;
    }

    //Construct a proportional size of new image
    $image_scale = min($max_size/$image_width, $max_size/$image_height);
    $new_width = ceil($image_scale * $image_width);
    $new_height = ceil($image_scale * $image_height);

    $new_canvas = imagecreatetruecolor( $new_width, $new_height ); //Create a new true color image
    imagealphablending($new_canvas,true);
    $success = imagecopyresampled($new_canvas, $source, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $image_width, $image_height);

    return true;
}
if(isset($_POST['sendFile'])) { 
    $image_name = $_FILES['image_file']['name']; //file name
    $destination_folder = "folder/";
    $sm_square_size = 300; //Thumbnails will ! be cropped 
    $sm_prefix = "_sm"; //Small thumb Prefix
    $md_square_size = 600; //Thumbnails will ! be cropped 
    $md_prefix = "_md"; //Medium thumb Prefix
    $max_image_size = 1200; //Maximum image size (height and width)
    $lg_prefix = "_lg"; //Large thumb Prefix
    $jpeg_quality = 90; //jpeg quality

    if($image_name != "") {
        $image_size = $_FILES['image_file']['size']; //file size
        $image_temp = $_FILES['image_file']['tmp_name']; //file temp
        $image_size_info = getimagesize($image_temp); //get image size
        //echo "Image ".$image_name." Uploaded. ";
        if($image_size_info){
            $image_width = $image_size_info[0]; //image width
            $image_height = $image_size_info[1]; //image height
            $image_type = $image_size_info['mime']; //image type
        } else {
            die("Make sure image file is valid!");
        }

        //switch statement below checks allowed image type 
        //as well as creates new image from given file 
        switch($image_type){
            case 'image/png':
                $image_res =  imagecreatefrompng($image_temp); break;
            case 'image/gif':
                $image_res =  imagecreatefromgif($image_temp); break;
            case 'image/jpeg': case 'image/pjpeg':
                $image_res = imagecreatefromjpeg($image_temp); break;
            default:
                $image_res = false;
        }

        if($image_res){
            //Get file extension and name to construct new file name 
            $image_info = pathinfo($image_name);
            $image_extension = strtolower($image_info["extension"]); //image extension
            $image_name_only = strtolower($image_info["filename"]);//file name only, no extension
            $dateRec = date('d-M-Y-h-i-s');

            //create a random name for new image (Eg: fileName_293749.jpg) ;
            $new_file_name = $dateRec. '_' .  rand(0, 9999);

            $thumb_name = $new_file_name.$sm_prefix.'.'.$image_extension;
            $medium_name = $new_file_name.$md_prefix.'.'.$image_extension;
            $large_name = $new_file_name.$lg_prefix.'.'.$image_extension;

            $thumb_path = $destination_folder.$thumb_name;
            $medium_path = $destination_folder.$medium_name;
            $large_path = $destination_folder.$large_name;


            $ftp_server = "";
            $ftp_conn = ftp_connect($ftp_server) or die("Could not connect to $ftp_server");
            $ftp_username = "";
            $ftp_userpass = "";
            $login_conn = ftp_login($ftp_conn, $ftp_username, $ftp_userpass) or die("Could not connect to ftp login");
            if((!$ftp_conn) || (!$login_conn)) {
                print "FTP connection failed!"; exit();
            } else {
                // upload a file

                if(thumb_resize_image_new($image_res, $image_temp, $image_type, $md_square_size, $image_width, $image_height, $jpeg_quality)) { 
                    echo "thumb created. $success <br />";
                } else { 
                    die('Error Creating thumbnail: '.$thumb_path.'<br />'); 
                }

                if(ftp_put($ftp_conn, $thumb_path, $image_temp, FTP_BINARY)) {
                    echo "Successfully uploaded $thumb_name <hr />";
                } else {
                    echo "There was a problem while uploading $thumb_name into $thumb_path <hr />";
                }

                if(ftp_put($ftp_conn, $medium_path, $image_temp, FTP_BINARY)) {
                    echo "Successfully uploaded $medium_name <hr />";
                } else {
                    echo "There was a problem while uploading $medium_name into $medium_path <hr />";
                }

                if(ftp_put($ftp_conn, $large_path, $image_temp, FTP_BINARY)) {
                    echo "Successfully uploaded $large_name <hr />";
                } else {
                    echo "There was a problem while uploading $large_name into $large_path <hr />";
                }

            }
            ftp_close($ftp_conn);   
        }   
    }
}
```

If anyone knows how to help fix this, or a better way of doing it, I'd forever be thankful!

Comment: Can you tell us the specific issue you are having? What do you expect to happen and what actually happens? And telling us what line is supposed to do this would also be nice.

Comment: @River I actually just think I figured out a method of fixing my issue I'm having. I originally was not getting the image to resize and move to website/server B. It was just moving over. But I currently have it working by uploading to server/website A, re-sizing, renaming, and then I move it to B. I can upload or edit this code if you wish. But I'd love to figure out how to do all that without actually uploading anything to server A.